# Detecting API Support through SecureWindow proxy object with Lightning Components LockerService

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, locker-service

When using device access APIs via Javascript, best practice would dictate to detect whether supported by the browser/webview and fail gracefully if not supported.

For instance, I have a component that I created to play with device orientation. So I have to add a function to the `deviceorientation` event handler like so:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', doOrientation);
```

This works just fine with locker service on or off. Meaning apparently the `window.addEventListener` proxy function is A-OK.

However, normally for device access features I would test for support before actually executing that logic. That would look something like this:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent ||){
  ...all the stuff I want to do now that the API is there...
}
```

Unfortunately, `SecureWindow`, the proxy API that LockerService surfaces in place of the real-DOM `window` object appears to not have that, or in any case, I end up with a falsy value.

So generally I'm looking for suggestions for how to test whether an API exists, when detecting whether that API exists is abstracted away because of LockerService. But I'd take an answer for how to detect how *this* API exists, if that's all you've got.